# How to upload a blob into firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

i'm using next js 13 with firebase v9. and i'm using a drop zone to upload images. the dropzone returns an array with blob as it's src.

```
[
  {
    id: 1
    name: "image_processing20220628-4591-yzir35.png"
    src: "blob:http://localhost:3000/6e2f33e5-a749-4e9a-b502-d20b8e3f38ca"
  }
 ...
]
```

the above array is returned from the drop zone. and when i tried to upload to firebase storage it throws an error .

```
FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'livingImages/blob:http:/localhost:3000/ca0e3eaf-dbe9-4d77-8053-f4b6d1bd8600' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)
```

so how can i upload blob of images to firebase storage?

```
 const imgURL = [];

 //this is the images stored inside Redux
 const images = useSelector(selectImages); 

  const storage = getStorage();
  images.map(async (file) => {
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `livingImages/${file.src}`);
    await getDownloadURL(storageRef).then((url) => {
      imgURL.push(url);
    });
  });

 const createDocument = () => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "livingPosts", session?.user?.email);
    const colRef = collection(docRef, "posts");
    addDoc(colRef, {
      name: "test upload",
      images: imgURL,
    });
  };
```

the dropzone code

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const images = useSelector(selectImages);
  const [files, setFiles] = useState(images == [] ? [] : images);

const {getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({
onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
     acceptedFiles.map((file, index) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = async function (e) {
          const options = {
            maxSizeMB: 5,
            maxWidthOrHeight: 1920,
            useWebWorker: true,
          };
          const compressedFile = await imageCompression(file, options);

          const tot = parseInt(acceptedFiles.length) + parseInt(files.length);
          if (tot > 9) {
            alert("select maximum of 9 images");
          } else if (parseInt(acceptedFiles.length) > 9) {
            alert("maximum images to be selected is 9");
          } else if (parseInt(files.length) < 9) {
            setFiles((prevState) => [
              ...prevState,
              {
                id: index,
                src: URL.createObjectURL(compressedFile),
                name: file.name,
              },
            ]);

            files.map((filename) => {
              acceptedFiles.forEach((newFile) => {
                if (newFile.name == filename.name) {
                  alert("a duplicate image is detected");

                  setFiles(
                    files,
                    files.filter((val) => val !== newFile)
                  );
                }
              });
            });
          } else {
            alert("something went wrong");
          }
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        return file;
      });
    },
})
```

and the output of the dropzone is

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `file.src` is **not** a blob but an object URL. You have not provided any code that can help us find where the blobs are coming from. output of `console.log(images, selectImages)` would be helpful. And you are trying to get download URLs without uploading them at first place based on the code shared.

Comment: do u want me to upload the dropzone code?

Comment: Yes, i.e. the function called when user selects/drops file. Also the output of logs mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @Dharmaraj check it now. i've added it

Comment: i stored the `preview` to the object `src`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need the actual [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) or [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) object to upload the file and not the object URL. You can set the blob in state as shown below:

```
setFiles((prevState) => [
  ...prevState,
  {
    id: index,
    src: URL.createObjectURL(compressedFile),
    blob: compressedFile, // <-- add blob
    name: file.name,
  },
]);
```

Then to upload the files and storing download URLs in Firestore document, try the following function:

```
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const uploadFiles = async () => {
  console.log(files);
  const promises = files.map((file) => {
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${file.name}`);
    return uploadBytes(storageRef, file.blob);
  });

  // upload all files
  const res = await Promise.all(promises);

  // get download URLs
  const links = await Promise.all(res.map((r) => getDownloadURL(r.ref)));
  console.log({ links })

  // Add Firestore document
  const colRef = collection(db, "livingPosts", session?.user?.email, "posts")
  const docRef = await addDoc(colRef, {
    name: "test",
    images: links,
  });
  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
};
```

You can call this function on a submit button click or any event when you want to start the upload.

Comment: the storage works, but it's not writing to firestore. it throws `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')` in line of `const colRef = collection(db, "livingPosts", session?.user?.email, "posts");` pointing after collection

Comment: @MohammedBekele `session?.user?.email` seems to be `undefined`. Best to log and check.

Comment: thanks, the session has expired, that's why it wasn't working. but now it does.

Comment: one more thing , the firestore docs are created as the number of the images. meaning inside the sub collaection it creates docs same number as the images length. now i have uploaded 5 images and the docs are 5.

Comment: My code above only adds one documents with an array field containing all the links. My best guess is that you are calling the function multiple times.

Comment: actually, i'm calling it once when some conditions are true

Comment: Are you sure its not in a loop or so? Do the log statements in my code print multiple times?

Comment: it works now, when i re run it. i used my code to add to firestore as i posted above.